# In IIS 7.5, rewrite rule is not being processed - results in 404 error

Tags: php, iis-7, rewrite

We currently have a rewrite rule with the Match defined as:

```
Req URL: Does not match pattern
Using: Regular Expressions
Pattern: &.*\.(css|gif|png|js|jpg|jpeg)$
Action Type: Rewrite
Properties:
   Rewrite URL: index.php
```

This is defined at the path `application/live` in which there is the `index.php`.

However, when we go to `https://ourhost.internal/application/live/child` it results in a 404. Should this not be rewriting that child to `index.php`?

If this -is- wrong, what can we do so that going to `https://ourhost.internal/application/live/child/etc` sends the request to `index.php` while passing along the request URI of `/child/etc/`?

Not sure why it isn't working

Comment: Read what FRT says, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: We set up FRT, but none of those logs are being generated